# Why are generated elements appearing below their parent element?

Tags: javascript, html, css

In this [repl.it](https://repl.it/@iamapersonthing/flappybirdsstage2) the SKY (generated by the script) is blocking the GREEN BLOCK and the CHARACTER.

Desired output: For the "sky" and "ground" to be BEHIND the character and the green block.

Can someone explain why this is occurring and how to solve it? I have tried various things such as changing the order in the CSS file, but that doesn't make any difference.

```js
var block = document.getElementById("block");
var hole = document.getElementById("hole");
//add this for the setInterval function
var character = document.getElementById("character");

hole.addEventListener('animationiteration', () => {
  var random = -((Math.random() * 300) + 150);
  var top = (random * 100) + 150;
  hole.style.top = random + "px";
});

//interval function runs every 10 milliseconds
setInterval(function() {
  var characterTop =
    parseInt(window.getComputedStyle(character).getPropertyValue("top"));
  character.style.top = (characterTop + 3) + "px";

}, 10);
```

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

#game {
  width: 400px;
  height: 500px;
  border: 1px solid greenyellow;
  margin: auto;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#character {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: rgb(255, 0, 149);
  position: absolute;
  top: 250px;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

#block {
  width: 50px;
  height: 500px;
  background-color: greenyellow;
  position: relative;
  left: 400px;
  animation: block 2s infinite linear;
}

@keyframes block {
  0% {
    left: 400px
  }
  100% {
    left: -50px
  }
}

#hole {
  width: 50px;
  height: 150px;
  background-color: white;
  position: relative;
  left: 400px;
  top: -500px;
  animation: block 2s infinite linear;
}

.sky {
  background-color: aqua;
  width: 400px;
  height: 500px;
  position: relative;
}

.ground {
  background-color: brown;
  width: 400px;
  height: 100px;
  position: relative;
  top: 500px;
}
```

```html
<div class="sky">
  <div class="ground">
    <div id="game">
      <div id="block"></div>
      <div id="hole"></div>
      <div id="character"></div>
    </div>
    
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: My network is blocking repl.it. Can you post a still image of what it should all look like?

Comment: What it should look like? I've explained, hopefully quite clearly, what the desired output is. Currently the SKY or GROUND overrides (blocks out, puts behind) the other elements - such as the character and the green blocks.

Comment: Where have you explained? I see no such description. You only have three sentences up there.

Comment: Is [this](https://repl.it/join/bmcinkgi-gustavorocha18) the desired result? If it is I'll post an answer to explain the changes and errors you made. Edit: Idk if that link works as expected, never used Repl.

Comment: That is -excellent. If you could include a detailed explanation (for beginners) that would be much appreciated. I will also improve my question.

Comment: Another related question in the same game if you're interested :) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66035313/set-interval-function-in-javascript-game-is-not-being-run-every-10-seconds

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you replied in the comments I'll give a detailed begginer explanation for the changes I made in [this repl](https://repl.it/join/bmcinkgi-gustavorocha18).

The first thing I did was to change your HTML structure from

```
<div class="sky"></div>
<div class="ground"></div>
<div id="game">
  <div id="block"></div>
  <div id="hole"></div>
  <div id="character"></div>
</div>
```

to

```
<div id="game">      
    <div class="sky"></div>
    <div id="block"></div>
    <div id="hole"></div>
    <div id="character"></div>
</div>
<div class="ground"></div>
```

Note: I'll refer to divs using their `#id` selectors.

With that structure you can apply `position: absolute` to your `#sky` div, and then use the `inset: 0`, `width: 100%` and `height: 100%` properties to change its position and size, so that it covers the whole `#game` div. I also applyed `z-index-1` so that it shows beneath the other content (I'll include reference and short explanation to all these properties in the end of the answer).

You can see that I've also positioned `#ground` under the `#game` and then repeated the properties `margin: auto` and `width: 400px` to make it align with the `#game`. I wouldn't align it this way, but since I don't know your intentions I tried to minimize the changes.

References:

[inset](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/inset): shorthand for `top; bottom; left; right`

[z-index](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp) defines order of DOM rendering.

I've fixed a few mistakes, like the syntax error in your js code (an extra parenthesis in line 14) and lack of closing tags, always close `div` tags!

Answer (score 1):

1. You don' need the sky element, you could define a `#game { background-color: aqua; ... }` for the #game
2. Use Absolute (position) to define a specific position of an element inside a relative element
3. Defined the z-index (z-axis) of the sky and floor. I have solve the issues in this pen:

   https://codepen.io/emmanuelpaul/pen/qBqOxRX

Comment: Another question, with some silly comments from an unhelpful user, here > do have a look if you're able :) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66035313/set-interval-function-in-javascript-game-is-not-being-run-every-10-seconds/66035478?noredirect=1#comment116754369_66035478

Answer (score 1):

Make sure all your `html` tags are all in right place, placement of css is not making much of a difference.

`HTML` should look something like:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <title>FlappyBird</title>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  </head>
  <body>

    <div class="sky">
    <div class="ground">


    <div id="game">
      
     
      <div id="block"></div>
      <div id="hole"></div>
      <div id="character">
        
      </div>
</div>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

`CSS`

```
*{
  padding:0;
  margin:0;
  
}

#game{
  width:400px;
  height:500px;
  border: 1px solid greenyellow;
  margin:auto;
  overflow:hidden;
}


#character{
width:50px;
height:50px;
background-color:rgb(255, 0, 149);
position: absolute;
top:250px;
border-radius:50%;

}

#block{
  width:50px;
  height:500px;
  background-color:greenyellow;
  position: relative;
  left:400px;
  animation:block 2s infinite linear;
}

@keyframes block{
  0%{left:400px}
  100%{left:-50px}
}

#hole{
  width:50px;
  height:150px;
  background-color:aqua; /* Added these */
  position: relative;
  left:400px;
  top:-500px;
  animation:block 2s infinite linear;

}



.sky{
  background-color:aqua;
  width:400px;
  height:500px;
  position: relative;
}

.ground{
  background-color:brown;
  width:400px;
  height:100px;
  position: relative;
  top-padding:500px; /* Added these */
}
```

`JS`

```
var block = document.getElementById("block");
var hole = document.getElementById("hole");
//add this for the setInterval function
var character=document.getElementById("character");

hole.addEventListener('animationiteration',() => {
  var random = -((Math.random()*300)+150);
  var top=(random*100)+150;
  hole.style.top=random +"px";
});

//interval function runs every 10 milliseconds
setInterval(function(){
  var characterTop = 
  parseInt(window.getComputedStyle(character).getPropertyValue("top"));
  character.style.top=(characterTop+3)+"px";
  
  },10);
```

[Here](https://codepen.io/maximuscode-the-looper/pen/qBqOxKx) is my example form codepen.io

Hope it helped you, let me know if this is what you were looking for!

Comment: Related question I'm having no joy with > https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66035313/set-interval-function-in-javascript-game-is-not-being-run-every-10-seconds/66035478?noredirect=1#comment116754369_66035478